# Keeping the script running when closing the window and opening a text editor in Python

Tags: python

As we all know April fools is coming so i tought i would write a nice script to prank someone, a harmless version of the well known and feared MEMZ Virus.

The Script i have currently:

```
import webbrowser
import time

def program():
    time.sleep(13)
    url = "https://www.google.nl/#q=TROLOL+GO+TO+LAUGH+IDIOT&*"
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
    time.sleep(16)
    url = "https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1CAACAG_enNL654NL655&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=CS:GO+Hacks+No+Download&*"
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
    time.sleep(18)
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S94ohyErSw"
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
    time.sleep(23)

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What i want is to be able to open a text editor with text just like in the real virus.
A windows error box would be fine to. Also i dont want the prompt. so a way to close the prompt without ending the script would be nice.

Anyone got some ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Natan.

EDIT: My victim's Computer has Windows.

EDIT2:
I have updated the script:

```
import webbrowser
import ctypes
import time

MB_OK = 0x0
MB_OKCXL = 0x01
MB_YESNOCXL = 0x03
MB_YESNO = 0x04
MB_HELP = 0x4000
ICON_EXLAIM = 0x30
ICON_INFO = 0x40
ICON_STOP = 0x10
ICON_QUES = 0x20

def program():
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Your computer is fucked by the MEMZ Trojan, good luck trying to keep using it.", "GET REKT, DABBBB", MB_OK | ICON_INFO)
    time.sleep(2)
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "BTW if you shut down your computer you wont be able to start it back up.", "Almost forgot....", MB_OK | ICON_INFO)
    time.sleep(13)
    url = "https://www.google.nl/#q=TROLOL+GO+TO+LAUGH+IDIOT&*"
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
    time.sleep(16)
    url = "https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1CAACAG_enNL654NL655&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=CS:GO+Hacks+No+Download&*"
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
    time.sleep(18)
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S94ohyErSw"
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
    time.sleep(23)
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Still using this computer?", "Hell is that way", MB_OK | ICON_QUES)
    time.sleep(17)
    url = "https://www.gottabemobile.com/black-ops-3-cheats-hacks-things-to-know/"
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
    time.sleep(12)
    url = "https://thepiratebay.org/"
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
    time.sleep(32)
    url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114927/keeping-the-script-running-when-closing-the-window-and-opening-a-text-editor-in"
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Trololol. Fijne 1 april nog Justus! Groetjes Natan!", "April fools", MB_OK | ICON_INFO)

def main():
    program()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: one upvote for the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try in-built library `ctypes` to bring a pop-up on the screen.

```
import ctypes 
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Your text", "Your title", 1)
```

Hope this helps.

you can actually use `pythonw.exe` file instead of `python.exe`
Try this [link](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/python/excerpts/chpt20/index.html?page=2) -  I haven't tried this thing but hopes it will help you for sure in hiding window console.

you have to simply change your python file extension from `file.py` to `file.pyw`
and its done No windows console will show up.

Comment: Awesome dude! Do you happen to have any idear on how to run the script without a prompt? or only shortly?

Comment: If you can add an idear to help me with that i will mark it as an answer.

Comment: the answer* Yes i know, for some reason i cant edit the previous comment.

Comment: Dude you are awesome, but is this also possible when turning it in to an exe?

Comment: Thank you for your awesome reply anyways, You are awesome.

Comment: Sorry dude, it is for april fools so the target shouldnt suspect a thing. So i have to use a .exe so i cant use that. sorry dude.

Comment: you have to simply change your python file extension from `a.py` to `a.pyw`
and its done No windows console will show up.

Comment: and why to use `.exe` why don't you use a batch file and execute it in a hidden way>
try this link : https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way

Comment: How to turn it into an bat without having to have python on his PC?
Yes i have python on edit pc but i dont have it installed on the victim's pc

Comment: It did do the trick, the prank is ready :) Thank you very much

Comment: Congratulations!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139640/discussion-between-that-one-and-abhishake-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @Abhishake gupta is good, you can also os module to open a notepad with some text.

```
import os
f = open('foo.txt','w')
f.write('Hello world!')
f.close()
os.system("notepad.exe foo.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks, I am sure this will come in handy sometime!

Comment: Dude, if you are online, join the link on abhishake's answer, need your help