# How to invert the entire screen in python

Tags: python

As you all know it is April fools today and i am working on this prank.
I already asked a question about this but that one is probably deep in the registers by now.

So, all my research is right here: [Keeping the script running when closing the window and opening a text editor in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114927/keeping-the-script-running-when-closing-the-window-and-opening-a-text-editor-in/43115774#43115774)

If you could tell me how to invert the entire screen that would be great! Thanks.

EDIT 1: Yes, i did find Python PIL, but that was only for inverting images, i need the entire screen to be inverted.

EDIT 2: Guys, i am begging you, help me, it needs to be done Today!!!

EDIT 3: I am working with Windows 10/8

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: I understand what you mean and i have read the rules, but i am very new to the program and i have been looking all over the internet already and didnt find a thing, this is why i cant show any errored code.
Nice to see that people are checking if the rules are being met

Comment: What OS are you working with ?

Comment: I am working with win 10/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way of doing this on windows is to use a python library that can emulate keypresses and use the windows shortcut that invert the screen (ctrl+alt+down).
If you install pyautogui it's as simple as that:

```
 Import pyautogui
 pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'alt', 'down')
```

Comment: Dude, You are the best!!! should have looked for windows shortcuts first i suppose...

Comment: No offense but this only works in win 7. but i found a way to still do it. Thanks I just use the windows key + the plus one, to open the magnifier and then ctrl alt i